# how can I disable checkbox for the same grid row using listener?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I have these two grid checkbox columns

```
xtype:'checkcolumn',
dataIndex:'FUN',
id:'fun',
listeners:{checkchange:'onFunChecked'},

xtype:'checkcolumn',
dataIndex:'FUN2',
id:'fun2',
listeners:{checkchange:'onFunChecked'}
```

So the grid has 3 rows and when I check the FUN checkbox from first row,I want to disable FUN2 from the same first row .

Right now I'm using

```
 Ext.getcmp('fun2').disable().
```

But the issue is, this is disabling the checkbox for all the three rows ,I only want to disable for the first row .Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the current row in the grid, not the entire column.

Assuming that `FUN2` is the second column (with column index 1), you can use the following code. This will re-enable the second column when the first is unchecked but you can adjust as you need.

You can try it with Sencha Fiddle, I tested with Ext JS 6.2.0 classic triton:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['check1', 'check1'],
            data: [{
                "check1": false,
                "check2": false
            }, {
                "check1": false,
                "check2": true
            },{
                "check1": false,
                "check2": false
            }]
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            store: store,
            columns: [{
                xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                text: 'Check1',
                dataIndex: 'check1',
                listeners: {
                    checkchange: function(column, rowIndex, checked, record, e, eOpts) {
                        const check2Cell = column.up('grid').getView().getCell(record, 1);
                        if (checked) {
                            check2Cell.addCls('x-item-disabled');
                        } else {
                            check2Cell.removeCls('x-item-disabled');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                text: 'Check2',
                dataIndex: 'check2',
            }],
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: cannot read properties of undefined( reading getCells()) -this error is coming ,dont know why

Comment: What is your Ext JS version and toolkit (modern or classic)?

Comment: we are using classic toolkit and version 'modern light@6.2.6.8'

Comment: Please check my edited answer. It's a little different but works in Sencha Fiddle.

Comment: Still does not work .Can you please help with this .I want same thing as this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20rt  but the difference is he has done it for checkboxes and I want it for checkcolumns.

Comment: I created [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3n9h) from the code above and it works. Maybe you have different Ext JS version from what you told. This is Ext JS 6.2.1.167 - Triton classic.

Comment: The fiddle you mentioned here and in your new question is very different because it has some checkboxes on a form and not in a grid.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. No,I have referenced same fiddle in my new question too .Yes,it uses a form and checkbox ,but I was wondering if we can do the same for a grid using checkcolumn.

Comment: I know it is the same fiddle, I meant checkboxes on a form are different issue from the checkbox column in a grid.